# How do you define a dynamic default value in a Debian package template?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, packaging, deb

I have a package where I want the administrator to enter a list of interface names. I'd like that list to have a default. Only each system has a different list (eth0, enp0s3, eno1, to list a few).

Here is an example about just that:

```
Template: iplock/public_interfaces
Type: string
Default: eth0
Description: Public Interfaces
 Enter a comma separated list of interface names that are connected to the
 Internet (public). For example: "eth0, eno1, enp0s3" (without the quotes).
 This will be saved in the system settings file. If necessary, you will be
 able to override these values by creating another file with different values
 or use "sudo dpkg-reconfigure iplock" to change the package settings.
```

Could the `Default: eth0` be set dynamically? Are there example of such in existing Debian packages?

*Note 1: I'm specifically using Ubuntu.*

*Note 2: The template above can be [found here on github](https://github.com/m2osw/iplock/blob/main/debian/iplock.templates).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of a question can be set dynamically, but [not using the template default](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/debconf-doc/debconf-devel.7.en.html#Default):

> Don't make the mistake of thinking that the default field contains the "value" of the question, or that it can be used to change the value of the question. It does not, and cannot, it just provides a default value for the first time the question is displayed. To provide a default that changes on the fly, you'd have to use the SET command to change the value of a question.

There are two ways to handle this.

1. If you can determine a suitable value equivalently when your package is installed or when your program runs, set the default to a placeholder value, and have your program use that at runtime. *I.e.*, don’t store `eno1` in the field, have `eno1` calculated at runtime unless the user has specified their own value.
2. If you want to provide a suitable value before the user is prompted, use `db_set` in your maintainer script. See [the “Libraries” section in `man debconf-devel`](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/debconf-doc/debconf-devel.7.en.html#LIBRARIES) for an example.